# How do fix newman error self signed certificate?

Tags: ssl, newman

I get this error when running newman v.3.2.0:

`#  failure               detail
1.  Error                 self signed certificate`

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Fixed this by running this:

`$ newman run examples/sample-collection.json --insecure`

instead of

`$ newman run examples/sample-collection.json`